# tabs not storing scope vars

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, angularjs

My markup:

```
<li active="active.search"><a href="#" ng-click="activate('search')">search</a></li>
<li active="active.lists"><a href="#" ng-click="activate('lists')">lists</a></li>
<li active="active.find"><a href="#" ng-click="activate('find')">find</a></li>
```

My code:

```
$scope.active = {
          search: true
        };

$scope.activate = function(li) {
      $scope.active = {};
      $scope.active[li] = true;
    }
```

First - the item I've set to be highlighted, doesn't actually get highlighted by default, however they do work when clicked.

Secondly - I'm trying to use what is actually active via:

```
if ($scope.active[0].search === true) {
... some values
}
```

Is this not correct? as I can't seem to make this work.

Comment: should ng-click="active('find')"> be ng-click="activate('find')">?

Comment: sorry typo, will correct - thanks

Answer (score 0):

`active` isn't an angular directive so you need to enclose the variable in angular brackets `{{ }}` like

```
active="{{active.search}}"
```

for angular to parse it.

Comment: I'm still not sure - as my condition inside if ($scope.active[0].search === true) { doesn't seem to parse, is there any other way to access whether which li has been selected like above?

Comment: Yeah you need to use `$scope.active.search === true`. `active` is an object, not an array. http://jsfiddle.net/0mj2cpgr/

Comment: But I'd suggest you take a bit more of an angular approach to this, something like: http://jsfiddle.net/3uc9g8s2/